# casting the string id to string object

Tags: android

I want implement the following code and I need a Persian string to display in the screen using the **Toast class**. But android studio does not accept. I have a Persian string in `string.xml`  and I want display it using **Toast object**. I do not know what to do?

```
String name;
name = (String) findViewById(R.string.stringname);// does not accept
```

Also please say me, Which method I should use to display the content of the  `string.xml` using **Toast class**

Comment: use the below answer it will work.. all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringname);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),arr[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
```

use this code you will get the output

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Context.getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) method:

```
String name = getString(R.string.stringname);
```

The [`Activity.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) would not work, because string resources are not views.

[This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) covers string resources in Android.

Answer (score 0):

To create Toast object you need to have context and string.
Context can be

`Context context = MainActivity.this;`

or

`Context context = getActivity();`

Then you create your Toast like this:

`Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.strings.your_string_id), Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();`

To learn more about [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) read the documentation. And about resources, check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)